# longtable width

Tags: longtable

I am using longtable and want to specify the width of a column, however this does not work for me, first column need to be 2 cm for instance:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{l{2cm}l}
A & B
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `p{2cm}` or define a new columntype using the `array` package

Comment: I see, thank you, I also want it to be fully flushed to the side, there is a small gap if I use p(2cm), how can I solve this?

Comment: A `longtable` environment is always centered.... so flushing to the side could be a little difficult. You can use `@p{2cm}` to get at least rid of some small spacing at the left margin. And please, don't change the question in comments...

Comment: Sorry, I meant `@{}p{2cm}` of course...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer always centred unless you left align it with `[l]` I think you meant to say

Comment: `\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{2cm}l@{}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, let's assume I just forgot about  `[l]` ;-)

Comment: The question here should be: do you *really* need a `longtable`? Wouldn't `description` be better for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{2cm}l@{}}
```

to left align the table (`[l]`), have no left border space in the first column `{@{}`), and set the first column in a parbox of width 2cm (`p{2cm}`).